# Consistency of bounded finitely axiomatized set theories

Tags: lo.logic

If $T$ is a consistent first order finitely axiomatized set theory having an axiom that defines V and the rest of axioms are all of the form:

$\forall x1 ..xn \in V  \exists x \in V \forall y \in V (y\in x \iff \phi)$

where $\phi$ is a formula in which only symbols $x1,..,xn,y$ occurrs free, that has all of its quantifiers bounded by $V$.

Now are there criteria a definition of V must meet in order to get $Con(T +  \forall x (x \in V) ) ?$

Comment: What precisely are the free variables of $\phi$? Is $y\notin y$ a $\phi$ you can use?

Comment: $x1,..,xn,y$ are the free variables in $\phi$. $T$ is meant to be a consistent first order set theory, so you cannot have $ y \notin y $ to be a $\phi$ since that renders $T$ inconsistent. The whole question is about whether $T$ can prove  $\exists x (x \notin V)$, so of course the consistency of $T$ is already assumed since otherwise the question becomes meaningless